UnityWebRequest.GetAudioClip returns empty AudioClip
I was just trying to simply change the AudioClip content of an AudioSource with a file on my local disk.
The file can be imported into Unity as an AudioClip and plays without problems, however when loaded with UnityWebRequest.GetAudioClip, absolutely no echoes come back; when checked in the AudioSource, the soundwaves are completely flatlined, though the audio still plays if I click on the waves.
Here is the code that I use:
    IEnumerator GetAudioClip()
    {
        string path = "C:/path_to_audio_file/audio.wav";
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip($"file://{path}", AudioType.WAV))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            tmpAudio = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
            audioSource.clip = tmpAudio;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetAudioClip());
    }

What could I possibly be doing wrong, and if so, how can I fix it?
What I have tried:

Converted the audio to .ogg
Put the audioSource.clip = tmpAudio portion outside of the coroutine


have you tried using a Uri instead? Maybe there is something wrong with the path ... you should also include a check whether the request actually succeeded after yield return www.SendWebRequest(); also do if(www.result != UnityWebrequest.Result.Success) { Debug.LogError($"Failed to load audio clip! Result: {www.result}\nError: {www.error}", this); }

The path could be the problem because it uses backslashes. You can replace them with forward slashes like this:
using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip($"file:///{path.Replace("\\", "/")}", AudioType.WAV))


I found out the reason. I add one additional slash after C:/ and now the audio loads as expected.
